# Why doesn't my Trust Spotlight Webcam Pro work on Microsoft Teams?

Tags: windows-10, webcam, microsoft-teams

My **Trust Spotlight Webcam Pro** works well enough for Zoom calls, but when I use it on MS Teams on Windows 10, the image simply shows as black, or the webcam returns a generic error. Why doesn't my Trust Spotlight Webcam Pro work on Microsoft Teams?

***EDIT: After a few months the Webcam started working again with MS Teams - I don't know why!***

[image: Trust Spotlight Webcam Pro]

Comment: Does [USB webcam does not work in Microsoft Teams call - Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/usb-webcam-does-not-work-in-microsoft-teams-call/6e370883-fdf8-43a2-b224-b03fae474903) answer your question?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because poster solved issue by waiting / simply trying again.

Answer (score 1):

#### The image simply shows as black

> This driver fix solves an issue where the webcam showed no image on Microsoft Teams.
>
> 1. Download the [file](https://dc1ikuqcporsz.cloudfront.net/data/16428_01_MS_TEAMS_FIX_do_not_use_if_cam_already_works_in_Teams.exe) from the website
> 2. Connect the webcam to a USB port
> 3. Run the installer file in your computer (do not unplug your webcam or restart the computer until the installation has been completed)
> 4. The webcam is ready for use
>
> NOTE: do NOT use this update if the webcam is detected in Microsoft
> Teams. Only use this file if your webcam is NOT detected in Microsoft
> Teams.

Source: [Trust.com - SpotLight Pro Webcam with LED lights](https://www.trust.com/en/product/16428-spotlight-pro-webcam-with-led-lights)